# Why do we need to create different processes for each client in a concurrent server in C?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, networking, unix-socket

I was working on a simple client server program, with the intention of creating a chat program. I am new to socket programming in C. I have learnt that, to serve multiple clients, the server needs to fork a new process each time a client connects. Each time a client requests connection, the `accept()` function returns a descriptor id and after the `fork()` the parent closes the id.

Instead I didn't close the ID, such that each new client will get a newid, when accept() is invoked.

```
nsockfd = accept(lsockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &cli_len);
```

now this is stored in 2 variables:

```
    if (client1 < 0)
    {   client1 = nsockfd;
        printf("if loop %d\n",nsockfd);
    }
    else 
    {   client2 = nsockfd;
        printf("else loop %d\n",nsockfd);
    }
```

Now rest of code is

```
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Hi client1 Nice to meet you.",inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));

        ret = send(client1, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("Error sending message");
            exit(1);
                }
        printf("SRV - %s\n", buf);
        strcpy(buf,"");
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Hi client2 Nice to meet you.",inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));
        if(client2 > 0)     
        {ret = send(client2, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("Error sending message");
            exit(1);
                }
        printf("SRV - %s\n", buf);
        strcpy(buf,"");
```

Here the code is working as intended; each client prints only one of the statements.

If this is a flawless method, why is it taught that `fork()` should be used for serving each client.

I am working on a localhost? Is this the reason that this code is working for me?

Comment: `fork()`ing of a new process per client is **one** way to go. As you discovered there seem to be other ways too.

Comment: +1 for very good first question, using OP provided formatting and actual code with well formed questions. Keep posting! Good luck to all.

Comment: @alk okay, is there anything wrong with the approach, especially if Iwant to build a chat system

Comment: @AmrithKrishna: If the multi-process approach is wrong? No. However, creating a new process is expensive. Parallelism you might also achieve using threads but processes. Also if communication between the clients is a mayor use case one should spend some thoughts on how this could be implemented.

Comment: It's not worth me writing a full answer this late on, but in case anyone reads this later it's worth noting that if users can only be connected in sequence they won't be able to chat.  Writing a TCP chat server in C generally you'd accept() connections, keep the file descriptors in an FDSET and select() for new data in a while loop.  No fork() required except to background the daemon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't a concurrent server if you don't either `fork()` or process the connection in a (new?) thread.  That's the definition of a concurrent server.

If I'm reading your code correctly, what you've got is a simple sequential server.  It can only process one connection at a time. That's fine if the computation required for each response is minimal, as in your example. It's not so good if the computation involves a lot of effort — access disk or database, for example.

Note that a sequential server design is completely legitimate.  So too is a concurrent server design.  They should be applied to different workloads.  Generally, though, a concurrent server will handle large traffic volumes better than a sequential server.  Imagine if Google used sequential servers for responding to search requests!

Another design uses a thread pool or process pool with one thread or process farming out the work to other threads or processes.  These are trickier to write so they work well.

Comment: okay I get that, But am still not clear about the fact that, Since am trying for building a chat system, and since for each client I will be creating a new process, shall I close the sockid returned by accept() each time in the parent server process before new client request comes, or Ishould close them only jsut before exiting the program.

Comment: Just to make myself clear, the whole snippet I have provided is in an infinite loop, and I have run 2 clients, and obtained outputs as intened, one of the message per client. If a single process can do this, then why dont we use them as such. Please do comment about will this create problems when I create blocking calls like recv()

Comment: @AmrithKrishna: Imagine you have dozen or hundrerds or even thousands of clients wanting to chat.

Comment: You need to close the socket returned by accept in the parent process. Otherwise, your parent process is going to run out of file descriptors, so further accepts will fail.